# what socket method will connect a Xamarion.IOS app with remote .NET-Standard app on Windows?

Tags: .net, sockets, websocket, xamarin.ios

The Xamarin.IOS app will eventually be released through Apple App Store.
The backend .NET-Standard app will be on a Windows 2019 server on AWS or Azure.

Backend app must handle very large number of connections with small and infrequent data messages.

Mobile app socket client connects to backend socket service, the two exchange messages, connection stays up until mobile user closes mobile app.

What is a reliable 24/7/365 method for this?  Websocket or other?